# Error when trying to export from pgModeler

Tags: postgresql

I get the following error when trying to export at simple database. Does anyone know how fix it?

pgModeler version: v0.9.2-aplha1

Build: 20181214 Qt 5.9.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with create extension `postgis`

when I had included `geometry/geography` columns in my database. I found a solution by exporting build code as SQL, then editing the command above to be specific to a schema. I.e.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH schema_name
```

(See https://programmer.group/postgresql-create-extension-with-schema-pg_catalog-privilege-exception-case.html )

And then running the code through a `psql` shell. I believe the issue is something to do with trying to edit the core code files.

Note: I am also a real beginner with SQL. PSQL 11, PgModeler v0.9.2-beta build Qt 5.12.2